# React Redux does not have time to work on first render because of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I take a name from the path and give it to useeffect->dispatch and if array empty navigate to='', if not empty must show array. Navigate always works on the first render, the second time work normally. I'm trying to change useEffect to useLayoutEffect, but it also works on the first render.

file

```
const { car } = useParams();
const { carArray } = useSelector(state => state.carStore);
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getCar(JSON.stringify(car)))
}, [car])

 return (<div>
{!carArray ? <Navigate to={"/"} : carArray.map..}
</div>)
```

api

```
export const getCar = createAsyncThunk(
   'get/car',
   async (str) => {
      const response = await axios.post("", str)
         .then((r) => {
            return r.data
         })
         .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
         })
      return response
   }
)
```

slice

```
builder.addCase(getCar.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
         state.carArray = action.payload
      })
```

console.log works like this

[image]

Comment: You're only logging errors from your post, so it appears you're not calling the API correctly.

Comment: Hello. In api everything is ok, normally the answer is obtained. The problem is that it is already doing a redraw before getting the array and navigate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because returning JSX always happens before `useEffect`, one solution is to create a state to handle the "loading" phase (the first render):

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
//...
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCar(JSON.stringify(car)));
    setLoading(false);
}, [car]);
//...
if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
} else {
    return (<div>
    {!carArray ? <Navigate to={"/"} : carArray.map..}
    </div>)
}
```

If your goal is to get the data during the first render, then `useEffect` is not the right way to go,it runs after the first render so it is abvious that the redux state is still an empty array then.

You have mentionned `useLayoutEffect` but it will not help achieving what you want, the only way is to dispatch `getCar` action earlier, before the component mounts, geting the id to pass to the function won't be a problem.

Comment: Hello․ Thanks for the answer․ Tried both, and this and with boolean in redux after fullfield, but it turns out the same

Comment: @Andrey get a look I updated my answer

Comment: Everything is clear, thank You. I don't know how the question was asked but You understood Me very well.